# Как правильно пишется союз "чтобы"?

Tags: синтаксис

Answer (score 1):

Союз  "чтобы"  пишется  всегда  слитно.
*"Трудно  представить,чтобы я не ответил на этот вопрос"*.
Не  путать  с  местоимением  "что" плюс частица "бы".
*"Трудно  представить, что бы со  мной  случилось, если бы я опоздал на  самолет"*.
Частицу бы можно опустить  или переставить  в другае  место: "что со  мной  случилось бы..." К местоимению  можно  задать  вопрос "что?", это член предложения, в данном случае, подлежащее. Союз  "не" является  членом предложения как служебная часть речи.

Comment: Ответьте, почему  частица не  в моем ответе  взята  в  кавычки? Чья это редакция? Я протестую!